# Button inside content panel in content page can not call div from master page to be displayed

Tags: html, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages, visibility

In my Master Page I have a div "ErrorDiv" that I want to call from my content pages to display my error. The problem is that if a button was included inside an Update Panel, div is not shown when I call it from code behind. I am sure there is a trick to resolve this issue, I appreciate your help.
Below is my code:

Master Page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMainForm" runat="server">
 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
 <asp:Panel id="CommonPanelError" runat="server"  CssClass="alertMSG"    
  visible="false">
  <div id="ErrorDiv" class="ErrorBox" >
   <table>
    <tr style="vertical-align:top">
     <td><img src="../Images/Icons/error.png"  alt="" style="vertical-            
      align:middle" id="img2" runat="server" />&nbsp&nbsp </td>
     <td style="width:200px">
      <span style ="font-weight :bold ">ERROR</span><br />
      <asp:Label id="errorMsgBox" runat="server" > errorTest  
      </asp:Label> 
     </td>
     <td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <a href ="#"><img onclick="CloseMyErrorBox();"  
      id ="closeErrorBox" src="../Images/Icons/warning4.png"  alt=""      
      runat="server" /></a>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table> 
  </div>
  </asp:Panel>
 </form>
</asp:Panel>
```

Content page:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPAll" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlInsuredID" runat="server">
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnphyCode" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/BAL/go.gif" />
   </asp:LinkButton>
  </asp:Panel>   
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind of my content page:

```
Protected Sub lnkBtnphyCode_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkBtnphyCode.Click

If Trim(txtPhysicianCode.Text) = "" Then
     Dim c As Panel = CType(Me.Master.FindControl("CommonPanelError"), Panel)
        If c IsNot Nothing Then
            c.Attributes.Add("display", "block")
        End If
     Dim c1 As Label = CType(Me.Master.FindControl("errorMsgBox"), Label)
     Dim str = c1.Text
     errDotNet(str)
else ...
```

N.B: errDotNet is a function that alerts message "str", and in our case it is  displaying "errorTest" which is the message inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

You must put Triggers inside update panel after ContentTemplate

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkBtnphyCode" />
</Triggers>
```

It requires full page request. So add the below line in your page load:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterPostBackControl(Me.YourControlID);
```

Comment: can you add a small explanation ? @GalaxMan

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. I discovered that adding triggers for a link button that contains image does not work. It should be an asp Button or a link button alone